# "a third" or "third"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, grammatical-number, numbers

I have something similar to this sentence:

> However, more than third of the students that select math courses in
>   the first term pass with higher grades.

Which is correct:

> More than third

Or

> More than a third

Comment: Fractions require an article  or number ahead of them...a third, the third, one third, a half, the half, one half....etc although you can say **Half of...** or just **Half...**

Comment: In your example "student" should be "students"  (you need the plural)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - More than a third
> - More than one-third

Either of those options is grammatical.

> - More than third

is ungrammatical in a context like this.